# Beginner Rails Migration & Column Options in ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, migration, database-migration

Quick question on `:null` option in ActiveRecord table creation.

Let's say I was to create a new table with a column `description`.

```
def change
    create_table :products do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.text :description, null: false
    end
end
```

If I don't have any `:presence` validation in my model regarding the `description` column, then shouldn't "nothing" be able to be passed into the description column? I'm not sure what `null: false` can do to stop me from passing nothing in since I don't have any validation in place.

Comment: if you dont need any presence validation on description, remove null: false from the migration. null false will make it compulsory that something must be there for description

Comment: `:null => false` tells your database not to accept ***NULL*** values. Go ahead and try to create a product with null description and tell me is it saved to DB or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails migration or schema options like `null: false` operate on database level (storage). If you tried to save record with empty description field, you would receive a database error (e.g. generated by PostgreSQL) wrapped in a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:`. On calling `object.valid?` the object would have been valid from the application point of view (Rails).

Rails validations like :presence operate on application level. In this case passing a null value would create an object which would return false on `valid?` and you could easily access error messages from the object by calling `object.errors.` If not bypassing validations, Rails would not allow you to save such a record to the database.

Comment: Thank you, is there a case scenario where this would be beneficial over validations? Because it seems like validations is a better solution to this.

Comment: Well, one of the situations might be that you would like to enforce some validations (so that you don't get messy database), because as I have mentioned previously, you can actually skip the validation on record in Rails before save.